# Chrome showing error as: Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on creating a Chrome Extension of an Image Cropping Widget. The code of my `popup.html` is as follows:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="widget_script" style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:5px;width:600px" rows="5" readonly></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var protocol=window.location.protocol;
        var host= window.location.host;
        var head=('<div id="wd_id" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></\script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="'+protocol+'//'+host+'Image_crop/cropimages/img_crop_widget.js'+'"><\/script>
    <script type="text/javascript">init_widget()<\/script>');
        document.getElementById("widget_script").innerHTML=head;
    </script>
</body>
```

The variables **protocol** and **host** take *protocol* and *host* from URL in the browser. When I tried to integrate this as a Chrome extension, it is not working. When it works perfectly, it displays following code in the textarea:

```
<div id="wd_id" style="margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/cropimages/img_crop_widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">init_widget()</script>
```

I have things few things like, placing the JS code in external JS file and and also calling the file in `manifest.json` calling it in my `popup.html`, but none worked.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or what else should I try to make it work?

Comment: You need to place all the code in an external file. You can't have any inline code.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From the [Chrome extension CSP docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution):

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline `<script>` blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

You **cannot** have inline scripts in your extension HTML like:

```
<script>alert("I'm an inline script!");</script>

<button onclick="alert('I am an inline script, too!')">
```

Rather, you must place your script into a separate file:

```
<script src="somescript.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do I invoke "alert" in the "somescript.js" from the html button?

Comment: Never mind found: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2#inline_scripts

Comment: Relaxing the default policy doesn't seem to work at all in Chrome v70.0.3538.77 https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing

Answer (score 32):

If you are using React with create-react-app:

1. create a `.env` file in project root
2. Add variable as follows: `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false`
3. Build the project again and load the extension again.

[Source](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/)

Comment: This works with react project which built directly from CRA(create-react-application), too.

Comment: If you are a CRA user, I can confirm this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with me. Also on React.

Answer (score 13):

You have to add `content_security_policy` to your `manifest.json` file:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-B+Qe/KNUDtGDd/m1g5ycAq1DgpLs9ubKmYTlOHBogC8='; object-src 'self'"`

You will find the hash from console.

[image]

Comment: what is the sha256-B+Qe/KNUDtGDd/m1g5ycAq1DgpLs9ubKmYTlOHBogC8= and where does it come from? It seems to change everytime I run my application.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as I was developing an extension. I removed the extension and loaded it again which made the error message disappear.

Comment: Same here, but this used to work, now it happens multiple times a day, and have to remove & add it every time. (It only happens within the popup.html though)