# Dynamically loading script file in background script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have loaded jQuery via the manifest.json and I now want he ability to dynamically load other local scripts (if needed).

I have tried the following

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('script.js'), function () {
    console.log("Script loaded")
});
```

But it gives this error

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-JNPQ...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

How can I fulfill what it asks for?

Comment: jQuery `getScript`  function will inline the local script which is prohibited. Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690781/debugging-scripts-added-via-jquery-getscript-function. You will need to do something like this: `<script src="script.js"></script>` as answered in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145522/chrome-showing-error-as-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-of-content-sec

Comment: But will embedding the script in the DOM work for a background script?

Comment: Give it a try and see else you can embed using other ways without inlining