# Firebase Chrome Extension - Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, google-chrome-extension

Getting this error when trying to run this as an extension, any thoughts??

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-SDElGe7fYNO4sezC+axo6JiF5P5uY6qAiaLldxOYZXk='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js'></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "**",
        authDomain: "**",
        databaseURL: "**",
        projectId: "**",
        storageBucket: "**",
        messagingSenderId: "**"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="myApp">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"> <br>
        <input id="birth" type="text" name="birth" placeholder="Birthdate">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Go" name="submit">
    </div>

    <div id="births" class="births"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",


  "browser_action": {
  "default_title":"Test",
  "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome showing error as: Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145522/chrome-showing-error-as-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-of-content-sec)

Answer (score -1):

You can't load code from the web, only from a package. This is because hackers could use that Javascript as a home base [as shown here.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing)

Rescource(s):
    https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy