# Rails, Chartkick and Blazer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I am trying to use Chartkick and Blazer in my rails app, I have followed a few tutorials and I cannot get the charts to display.

All I see in the view is Loading...

This is the same for Chartkick and Blazer.

I am getting this error in the chrome javascript console

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https:". Either
>   the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-+5/81+EOJ9YzViagrir4B2/NDOE23fD9YahxuHgGtIM='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Try changing browser, did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145522/chrome-showing-error-as-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-of-content-sec

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried in Opera, safari, firefox and IE / Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I just added instructions for [CSP with Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/blob/master/guides/Content-Security-Policy.md).