# I am doing a chrome extension with react but it refuses to execute inline script

Tags: reactjs

So I am doing a chrome extension with react and when I compile it down to static js it will create inline script and that I am fully aware off therefore I have added

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-5As4+3YpY62+l38PsxCEkjB1R4YtyktBtRScTJ3fyLUQ='; object-src 'self'"
```

but chrome still throws this error

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'sha256-5As4+3YpY62+l38PsxCEkjB1R4YtyktBtRScTJ3fyLUQ='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-5As4+3YpY62+l38PsxCEkjB1R4YtyktBtRScTJ3fyLU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Am I missing something?

Here's the github repo if you wanna check the code
https://github.com/Hugo-Persson/NewTabExtension

[Screenshot of the error chrome throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6HJa.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution

You cannot have inline scripts in your extension HTML (Reference - [Chrome showing error as: Refused to execute inline script because of Content-Security-Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145522/chrome-showing-error-as-refused-to-execute-inline-script-because-of-content-sec)).

You must use something like:

`<script src="index.js"></script>`

Referencing: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/801

A user had an issue with his `<meta>` tags specifically `'unsafe-inline'; media-src *`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

I would ensure you are not violating what it literally says you are in violation of by checking meta and script tags.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
Just add **.env** file to the root of your React project with text

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
```